# angularjs - isolate scope between multiple different directives

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create three different directives that need to communicate together, and this isn't really a problem but I would like to explore the possibility of using an isolate scope, or at least as small a scope as possible between them.

Because sharing directly on the controller scope is so discouraged, I enacted this to try and get around that. The only solution I've seen immediately is to make all three behaviors in the same single directive, so that they all use the same scope - but this is very messy.

This is an *extremely* slim example of how it works. The full code is very long and it's not useful without a lot of extra context. I'm trying to trim it down to just what I need help with.

### 1. Is there a better way to share these `scope` properties between the directives?

### 2. Can I do it using an isolate scope, to reduce the clutter and load on the controller?

### 3. The reason for sharing information is a bit hard to explain briefly.

## directives

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('dataSourceUrl', ['$parse', function($parse) {
   return {
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 10,
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            var path = attributes.dataSourceUrl;
                
            angular.extend(scope.options, {
                /* more code */
            });
        }
   }
}])
.directive('dataSourceOptions', 
    ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 9,
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            var options = scope.$eval(attributes['dataSourceOptions']);
            
            angular.extend(scope.options, {
                /* more code */
            });
        }
    }
}])
.directive('dataSourceColumns', 
    ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 9,
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            var columns = scope.$eval(attributes.dataSourceColumns);
            
            angular.forEach(columns, function(value, key) {
                switch(value) {
                    case "Id":
                        scope.options.columns.push({ field: "Id" /* more code */ });
                        break;
                    case "Name":
                        scope.options.columns.push({ field: "Name" /* more code */ });
                        break;
                    /* more code */
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

## notes

My experience with angular is minimal, I am very new. I have researched isolate scope extensively, but it is proving to be more difficult than I thought. My goal is to use these directives kind of like this ...

```
<div kendo-grid data-source-url="'path/to/data'" 
     data-source-options="options" 
     data-source-columns="['Id','Name','Abbreviation','Group']">
</div>
```

Comment: multiple isolate scoped directive on same html element do actually share their scopes. best way of sharing data depends on how the two directives are related.

Comment: And that is precisely what I am hoping for. I am just having a very hard time finding examples of it, and interpreting it.

Comment: you would need to read docs on angularjs scopes, nothing else can help. the topic is too deep to be explained here. sorry.

Comment: I have read that documentation dozens of times, and it is not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can have multiple isolate scoped directive on same element. though as far as i remember, read it somewhere, that multiple isolate scoped directive do share the scopes.

you can read more about scopes [here](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/beginner2expert-scopes.html)

regarding sharing the data between directives, are the directives independent or are they in parent-child relationship?

if parent child then use `require` property of directives. and pass data only to parent directive and access it in child directive.

if they are sibling or independent, pass data to each directive separately.

lets assume that `dataSourceUrl` display changes on basis of parameters in `dataSourceOptions`. then you can use require property.

```
.directive('dataSourceUrl', 
    ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'dataSourceOptions'
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ctrlOptions)
               {
                         //ctrlOption.showHeadeers or something
                }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "parent-child"? You mean does directive2 depend on directive1? I'm not sure how that terminology works in this context.

Comment: I am not certain how these would classify. Each directive represents one HTML attribute, basically. But all three of them together form the collective behavior.

Comment: in that case, I would define them not as 3 directives, but one directive with multiple parameters.

Comment: Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/6umqG45rgk8rjvldeCz9?p=preview - if you look at the console, it actually throws an error with all three trying to get their own isolate scope. But ideally, I would like for the final object that gets output to have the contents given to it by all three directives.

Comment: exactly.. create one directive with multiple options rather than multiple directives.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "multiple options", just to make sure I'm on the same page here?

Comment: Also, that link is __incredible__. Best docs I've seen for scopes so far.

Comment: scope : { options: '=', url: '@', column: '='  }  so you receive multiple options in single directive.

Comment: Hrnm. I am still getting the error `Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [firstDirective, secondDirective] asking for new/isolated scope on: <div first-directive="" second-directive="" third-directive="">`

Comment: keep just one directive and remove http://plnkr.co/edit/5Xxv5nRdIWC6ixX6zGgL?p=preview

Comment: Maybe. But I am not sure if that is an option. Some of the directives may be used without the others in certain situations.

Comment: parameters are always options, so even if not passed, no harm. pass it only in those directives need them.

Comment: There is still a problem with getting the model in the directive. I think I'll need to open a separate question for that, though.

Comment: Yes, that would be better

Comment: The specific query about the model on the isolated scope is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750675/angularjs-getting-controller-model-from-isolate-scope-directive

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fiddle where two directive are integrated

http://jsfiddle.net/Wijmo/MTKp7/

and code is

```
angular.module("btst", []).
directive("btstAccordion", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        template:
            "<div class='accordion' ng-transclude></div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            // give this element a unique id
            var id = element.attr("id");
            if (!id) {
                id = "btst-acc" + scope.$id;
                element.attr("id", id);
            }

            // set data-parent on accordion-toggle elements
            var arr = element.find(".accordion-toggle");
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                $(arr[i]).attr("data-parent", "#" + id);
                $(arr[i]).attr("href", "#" + id + "collapse" + i);
            }
            arr = element.find(".accordion-body");
            $(arr[0]).addClass("in"); // expand first pane
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                $(arr[i]).attr("id", id + "collapse" + i);
            }
        },
        controller: function () {}
    };
}).
directive('btstPane', function () {
    return {
        require: "^btstAccordion",
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            title: "@",
            category: "=",
            order: "="
        },
        template:
            "<div class='accordion-group' >" +
            "  <div class='accordion-heading'>" +
            "    <a class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse'> {{category.name}} - </a>" +

            "  </div>" +
            "<div class='accordion-body collapse'>" +
            "  <div class='accordion-inner' ng-transclude></div>" +
            "  </div>" +
            "</div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch("title", function () {
                // NOTE: this requires jQuery (jQLite won't do html)
                var hdr = element.find(".accordion-toggle");
                hdr.html(scope.title);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

and also you can see the accordion example from this js

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.js

Comment: I am a little confused about how they are integrated. Don't misunderstand, I am very thankful for the help, I am just not sure how I'm supposed to interpret this. I'm not using `template` or `transclude` at all. They only seem to relate to each other in that they call DOM elements through jQuery.